# Create a horizontally Scrolling Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to build a simple page layout with tabs at the top that scroll horizontally, and content at the bottom that scrolls vertically under the tabs.

I have managed to get the vertical scrolling working, and to get the tabs to stay at the top, but I am having trouble getting the tabs to scroll horizontally.  How can this be accomplished?

Below is what I have so far. For simplicity's sake I have removed all functionality and am just working with the layout. I am using react

**the react component:**

```
var SimpleTabs = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        var lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ";
        var sampleText = lorem + lorem + lorem + lorem;

        return(
            <table className={"simple_tabs"}>
                <tr>
                    <td className={"tabsCell"}>
                        <div className={"tabs"}>
                            <span className={"tab"}>{"tab1"}</span>
                            <span className={"tab"}>{"tab2"}</span>
                            <span className={"tab"}>{"tab3"}</span>
                            <span className={"tab"}>{"tab4"}</span>
                            <span className={"tab"}>{"tab5"}</span>
                            <span className={"tab"}>{"tab6"}</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td className={"contentCell"}>
                        <div className={"content"}>
                            {sampleText}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            );
    }
});
```

**the less file:**

```
.simple_tabs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs > .tab {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.tabs{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}

.tabsCell{
  height: 20px;
}

.contentCell .content {

  height:100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: the width of the parent for the content will need to be greater than the width of all it's children combined. If you're using divs for content, you will need to set their width as well.

Comment: thanks @Ted! Why doesn't `overflow-x: scroll` take care of that?

Comment: Essentially, because if nothing is **told** to render outside the parent (overflow), nothing scrolls.  You can also absolutely position the children. It's hard to tell exactly which part you're having trouble with without a functioning sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/02r78hx2/), with plain old html.

One addition you may need is `table-layout:fixed` for the table.

Hopefully it will get you pointed in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks @Ted!
It seems to me that you have set a really large fixed width on the horizontally scrolling element in order to get this to work. That seems kind of hacky to me, but is a solution that I have read about elsewhere. Is it really the best way to do it?

Comment: If you change the elements to display:inline, you can use the white-space example mentioned below. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02r78hx2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.tabs` to allow elements inside to overflow the container.

```
.tabs{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```